# R: aggregate similar columns and use column name as value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
ID  FactorA FactorB Industry1 Industry2  Curr1   Curr2
1   1.121   0.121   1         0          1       0
2   1.52    0.114   0         1          1       0
```

Factor A and Factor B are real numbers and all of them have values. However `Industry1` and `industry2` (same for currency 1 and currency 2) are binary, ie only one of them can have `value=1`.

Since I want to shrink the data for storage purposes as I have 80 Industry types and 100 currency types and only one of them have values, I want to store them like this

```
ID  FactorA FactorB Industry    Curr
1   1.121   0.121   Industry1   Curr1   
2   1.52    0.114   Industry2   Curr1
```

Basically I want to use the column names where the value is 1 and join all the strings where `type=Industry`, `Curr` etc. I do have another table that links each column name to its type

```
ColName     Type
FactorA     Factor
FactorB     Factor
Industry1   Industry
Industry2   Industry
Curr1       Curr
Curr2       Curr
```

Comment: You should use `dput` to provide a reproducible answer of a sample of your data.frame (something like `dput(mydataframe[1:5, ])`

Comment: Thanks. I was struggling how to present the data.

Comment: Please stop rolling back our improvements to your formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You can collapse columns using the `melt` function from the `reshape2` package. As mentioned in the comments, provide an example - it makes life easier:

```
dd = data.frame(ID = 1:2, factorA = c(1.121, 1.52),
  factorB = c(0.12, 0.114), Ind1 = 1:0, Ind2= 0:1,
  Curr1 = 1, Curr2=0)
```

First load the package:

```
library(reshape2)
```

Next `melt` the columns, but protect the first three:

```
dd1 = melt(dd, id=1:3)
```

Look at the melt help file for more information. Then just a bit of subsetting to get what you want:

```
dd2 = dd1[dd1$value == 1,]
```

You will probably want to drop the final column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ifelse` to create the new columns:

```
mydata$Industry = ifelse(mydata$Industry1, "Industry1", "Industry2")
mydata$Curr = ifelse(mydata$Curr1, "Curr1", "Curr2")
```